# Why this vector won't scale in unison?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a vector logo and I need to upscale it to 6000 pixels, but for some reason, when I resize it, the whole thing doesn't resize, even if they are grouped...

Stretches as far as about 2000 px, but over that it breaks...

The canvas is set to 8000 also in case that's the problem?

[image]

Comment: I assume that's live type. What is the point size?

Comment: Also why are you resizing in pixels? Assuming everything is vector then you can output at whatever size you like, no need to resize in Illustrator.

Comment: Fonts are in pixels now, should I change to points? The get it done and .com expands fine, but the X and the xuzo don't...

Comment: Points = pixels in illustrator. The unit doesn't matter anyway. There is a max point size of 1296pt so if you're trying to scale it larger than that, that's your problem. Outline your type if you need to, but there's rarely any reason to actually work that big.

Answer (score 1):

The point size was the problem, I turned the image into outlines and it worked.

Thanks for the answer Cai.